# Windows 7: Is there a way to create a "choose language" shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, language-pack

We have loaner PCs to give out to our guests. One of the requirements was the Spanish MUI. We have it installed and working, but I am wondering: Is their an easier way to change languages that `control panel -> region -> language settings`? Perhaps a keyboard shortcut we can set up, or a batch file we can create?

Comment: Maybe try creating a new account just for them? I'm not sure if it'll work in windows. In GNU/Linux systems each user can usually have his own locale  and language settings.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there's a keyboard shortcut for it, you'll have to first create a script/program that do the setting change, and then assign it to a keyboard shortcut.